# Select Duplicates with distinct/DIFFERENT names

Tags: sql, sql-server, duplicates, distinct

I have Articles base:

| INDEKS_KATALOGOWy | ID_MAGAZYNU | Nazwa |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Opa000001 | 1 | Węgiel |
| Opa000001 | 6 | Węgiel |
| Opa000001 | 7 | Węgiel |
| Opa000002 | 1 | Węgiel brunatny |
| Opa000002 | 6 | Węgiel brunatny |
| Opa000002 | 7 | Węgiel brunatny |
| PRO000001 | 1 | Pasta 10 ml |
| PRO000001 | 6 | Pasta 10 ml |
| PRO000001 | 7 | Pasta 10 ml |
| PRO000001 | 8 | PASTA 10 ml |
| ROL000001 | 1 | Artykuły rolnicze |
| ROL000001 | 6 | Artykuły rolnicze |
| ROL000001 | 7 | Artykuły rolnicze |

This is selection by query:

```
select indeks_katalogowy, ID_MAGAZYNU, Nazwa
from artykul

where indeks_katalogowy in (Select INDEKS_KATALOGOWY 
    from ARTYKUL
    Group by INDEKS_KATALOGOWY, NAZWA
    having count(*) >1)
```

And I have to display ONLY articles with DIFFERENT Names
so I want to only show:

| INDEKS_KATALOGOWy | ID_MAGAZYNU | Nazwa |
| --- | --- | --- |
| PRO000001 | 1 | Pasta 10 ml |
| PRO000001 | 6 | Pasta 10 ml |
| PRO000001 | 7 | Pasta 10 ml |
| PRO000001 | 8 | PASTA 10 ml |

because Pasta 10ml and PASTA 10 ml are different

Comment: Hi - please format your data as tables (https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/302471/how-to-put-tables-in-stack-overflow) and your code as code - so that it is readable

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Im Using MS SQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `exists` as follows:

```
select indeks_katalogowy , ID_MAGAZYNU, Nazwa
from artykul t
 Where exists
  (Select 1 from artykul tt
    Where t.indeks_katalogowy = tt.indeks_katalogowy
      And t.Nazwa != tt.Nazwa )
```

Comment: Considering that the OP's example is `'Pasta 10 ml'` and `'PASTA 10 ml'`, this isn't likely to work; *most* people are in a case **in**sensitive collation, so the 2 values would be treated as equal.

Comment: Assumption that database is case insensitive? One can use` COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS` in the query to make it case **sensitive**

Comment: "*Assumption that database is case insensitive?"* That's what I'm saying, yes. It's quite rare for databases (and especially instances) to be in a case sensitive collation (and they really are a pain to work with when they are). It tends to be that specific columns that need to be case sensitive are explicitly collated to a case sensitive collation.

Comment: I decided to use this. Thank You

Answer (score 2):

If Pasta 10ML and PASTA 10ML are different then you would need to change to Collation on the column to reflect this.  You also would only need to group by INDEKS_KATALOGOWY

```
select indeks_katalogowy, ID_MAGAZYNU, Nazwa
from artykul

where indeks_katalogowy in (Select INDEKS_KATALOGOWY 
    from ARTYKUL
    Group by INDEKS_KATALOGOWY
    having count(DISTINCT Nazwa COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS) >1)
```